# Unable to stop VMs using Azure Automation

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-automation

We have an Azure Service Fabric cluster set up and I'm attempting to use Azure Automation to stop the virtual machine scale set and restart on a schedule. The scale set is assigned to a resource group as follows

[image]

My Exteral_Start_ResourceGroupNames and External_Stop_ResourceGroupNames, which the ScheduledStartStop_Parent runbook uses is as follows:

[image]

You can see the resource group name matches the resource group name for my VM scaleset. My understanding is that when the runbook fires, all VMs in this resource group, and, therefore, the VM set, should be stopped. However, when the runbook fires, it's not finding any VMs to stop.

Can anyone see what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although they are both VMs, "Virtual Machines" and "Virtual Machine Scalesets" are different resource types in Azure. The underlying nodes of a scaleset are not exposed as 'normal' VMs. You could probably modify your start/stop script to find scalesets in those resource groups instead of normal VMs.

To get you started: The powershell command for finding ScaleSets is [Get-AzureRmVmss](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-manage-powershell). That page also details how to shut them down.

Comment: Got it. This seems a rather odd limitation to me. The individual nodes that make up our SF cluster aren't even exposed as resources. So I cannot assign them to a resource group for Automation to stop.

Comment: I think the philosophy behind the scaleset is that you no longer need to manage your individual nodes, but only operate against them on a scaleset level: you stop a scaleset, not a VM. Shutting down service fabric nodes one by one would get a lot of errors once you drop below quorum, so better to stop the scaleset if you want to free up the underlying compute.

Comment: Right, I understand that. But it would be nice though if Azure provided a runbook to stop a scaleset in addition to VMs in a resource group.